How should I fix bathroom under sink hot water valve?

This valve looks weird and can't really find any similar pictures online. The valve stem directly goes into the supply line...
Believe we may need to replace the valve but just not sure what kind of parts I should get.

Does it work(turn off and turn on)?  Does it leak?

It can't turn off completely - maybe up to 99% shutoff? Or the valve stem is dripping.

There is a set screw holding the fange on the wall.  Removing that should let you see into the wall where the valve is.

A picture showing the valve body would be helpful. In general, though, for a multi-turn valve one can replace the packing (the seal around the valve stem) and the actual valve seal.
